# Xml Serialize float value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, floating-point

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.TotalInclTax = 4194.00f;
invoice.serialize();
```

I need some help in serializing float value. Currently it serializes 4194.00 as following:

```
<TotalInclTax>4194</TotalInclTax>
```

But, I want something like this:

```
<TotalInclTax>4194.00<TotalInclTax>
```

Comment: You have to change your `serialize` method in `Invoice` class. Maybe put something like this there: `String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalInclTax);`

Can you show us that class, or just `serialize` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adapt your class a little to customize how TotalInclTax will be serialized :

```
static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
float _TotalInclTax = 0;

[XmlIgnore]
public float TotalInclTax 
{
    get { return _TotalInclTax ; }
    set { _TotalInclTax  = value; }
}

[XmlElement("TotalInclTax")]
public string CustomTotalInclTax
{
    get { return TotalInclTax.ToString("#0.00", ci); }
    set { float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, ci, out _TotalInclTax); }
}
```

Comment: it would be a good idea to explicitly specify a culture here, too

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem if you use the deserialize methods to retrieve the value. It should put the decimal point and other digits if you try to serialize a value with non-zero values after the decmial point like 4672.34

But if for other reasons you absolutely need to control the decimal point formatting I would say serialize it as a string and use the string printing formatting for a float to set the string value and read the string value back into a variable of type float.